# Use the same copying technique as NSScrollview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, copy, nsscrollview

The NSScrollView copies its document view when it is scrolling. How can I use this same idea of copying a part of my view to paste it later when everything has moved.

Comment: What are you really teeing to do? Why doesn't NSScrollView meet your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to [create a bitmap image rep for caching purposes](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect%3a) and [cache to it](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/cacheDisplayInRect%3atoBitmapImageRep%3a). You can then either [draw it directly](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImageRep_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImageRep/drawAtPoint%3a) or wrap it in an NSImage and draw that.